XAMPP Not Working After macOS 15 Update: Apache Won't Start
I've recently updated my Mac to macOS 15, and since then, my XAMPP installation has stopped working. Specifically, Apache won't start, and I can't seem to figure out why. Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, were you able to resolve it, and how? Additionally, I'm looking for recommendations on alternative programs to XAMPP that work well with macOS 15. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Here's what I've tried so far:

Reinstalled XAMPP: No change, Apache still won't start.
Tried Docker: Set up a Docker container for my development environment, but faced issues with Apache not running correctly.
Installed MAMP: Attempted to switch to MAMP, but encountered the same issue where Apache wouldn't start.
I was expecting at least one of these solutions to work, but none have resolved the problem. Has anyone else faced similar issues after updating to macOS 15? If so, how did you manage to fix it? Also, I'm open to suggestions for alternative programs that are compatible with macOS 15 and can serve as a replacement for XAMPP. Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!


Homebrew is a pretty popular alternative to set this up on Mac. https://www.git-tower.com/blog/apache-on-macos/, https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/

Are you sure your problem is related to phpMyAdmin after all? Maybe the tools are not yet compatible with MacOS 15 (which is in preview state since this week and should not used for anything productional after all!)

Do you have found any solution? I have the same issue and I tried the same options as you did

On MacOS the best options are

Herd - if you use Laravel
Docker with NGinx
or the standard LAMP, try install with HomeBrew


Thank you for the helpful suggestions! I appreciate the recommendations. I'll give Herd, Docker and the standard LAMP a try. Your advice is much appreciated!

I have faced the same problem. I even installed MAMP, but the Apache server still won't start. I had to roll back to Sonoma."

After I updated the MacOS 15 beta 2 I use MAMP and It works properly already but you have to deal with newer mysql version if you are using xampp also I have to change all of my PHP script to match with new MySQL version
